# Can a .NET SAAS application allow users to update their CSHTML from the app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So there are services like Shopify, Wordpress, and many others that allow a user to update their layout from the app itself, in the browser, but many of these aren't written in a compiled language like from the .NET framework.

Is this type of thing possible from a .NET MVC site? Can I allow a user to modify their `.cshtml` file as long as they adhere to the `Razor` conventions?

Is there a downside to this for a compile language?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. If you are familiar with .NET Framework products you know that using asp.net mvc routing and just a little bit of custom code you can produce your own controller that handle user's request and manage custom views.

For example you can save users view into a table and build an editor.
After, you can write a controller that handle user's requests and render required views. Please view this really short example.

You can create a table like this that will run as link between physical views and user's related views.

```
CREATE TABLE UserPages (
 Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 Title NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 Html NTEXT NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE UserPages ADD CONSTRAINT PK_UserPages PRIMARY KEY (Id);
```

The controll will be similar to this:

```
class UserPagesController : Controller {
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Save(UserPage page) {
        var db = new DbContext(); // Your db context..
        db.Save(userPage);
        var path = string.Format("~/Views/UserPages/Page{1}.cshml", page.Id);
        path = Server.MapPath(path);
        File.WrileAllText(path, page.Html);
        return ...;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult View(int id) {
        var db = new DbContext();
        var page = db.Pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if( page != null) {
            var path = string.Format("~/Views/UserPages/Page{1}.cshml", page.Id);
            return View(path);
        } else {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }   
}
```

Please remember: this is just an example to guide you in the process. You have to learn how asp.net mvc works and how to it very well. But, I think, this is a good start point.

I hope this can help.